# Оптимизация множество Мандельброта

Tags: python, оптимизация

Я сделал программу в которой можно приближать множество Мандельброта

у меня вопрос как его можно оптимизировать?

```
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

I = (-1) ** .5
maxiter = 64

def f(z, c):
    return z * z + c

def mandelbrot(x, y, scale):
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for i in range(500):
        for j in range(500):
            i0, j0 = i / scale + x, j / scale + y
            
            i0 = i0 / 250 * 2 - 2
            j0 = j0 / 250 * 2 - 2
            
            c = (i0 + j0 *I)
            
            z = 0
            
            for depth in range(maxiter):
                z = f(z, c)
                if abs(z) > 100:
                    break
            
            
            c = depth * (255 / maxiter)
            gfxdraw.pixel(win, i, j, (c, c, c))

            
        pygame.display.update()

mandelbrot(0, 0, 1)
x, y, scale = 0, 0, 1

while True:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x0, y0 = ev.pos
            
            x0 -= 50
            y0 -= 50
            
            x0 /= scale
            y0 /= scale
            
            x += x0
            y += y0
            
            scale *= 5
            
            mandelbrot(x, y, scale)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал ускорение вычисления картинки с помощью библиотек `Numpy` и `Numba`. Отрисовку делаю один раз сразу всей картинки, это тоже ускоряет процесс.

```
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw,surfarray

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

import numpy as np
from numba import njit

I = (-1) ** .5
maxiter = 64

@njit(fastmath=True)
def f(z, c):
    return z * z + c

@njit(fastmath=True)
def mandelbrot(x, y, scale):

    pic = np.zeros((500,500,3), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(500):
        for j in range(500):
            i0, j0 = i / scale + x, j / scale + y
            
            i0 = i0 / 250 * 2 - 2
            j0 = j0 / 250 * 2 - 2
            
            c = (i0 + j0 *I)
            
            z = 0
            
            for depth in range(maxiter):
                z = f(z, c)
                if abs(z) > 100:
                    break

            c = depth * (255 / maxiter)
            pic[i, j] = np.array((c.real,c.real,c.real), dtype=np.float64)

    return pic

def mandelbrot_draw(x, y, scale):
    pic = mandelbrot(x, y, scale)
    surfarray.blit_array(win, pic)
    pygame.display.update()

mandelbrot_draw(0, 0, 1)
```

Update: Починил тип данных и добавил код для разовой отрисовки.

Comment: Я тоже попробовал ваш вариант через `surfarray.blit_array(win, pic)` (не уверен, что это правильный вариант, pygame не пользовался) и вывело белую картинку. Если не стоит pygame, можете поиграться в виртуальном окружении https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalHarmlessMigration

Comment: @dIm0n Что-то никак не могу понять, где собака порылась. Как только начинаю в numpy array данные писать, так что-то теряется явно. Я уж и типы разные пробовал...

Comment: @dIm0n Вроде починил, надо было float64 массив делать. И добавил отрисовку. Вроде быстро фигачит

Comment: А всё, понял, поставьте индентацию `return` левее

Comment: @dIm0n А, точно. Я уже у себя давно исправил и забыл )

Comment: Вот окончательный вариант с приближениями, работает в разы быстрее кода ТС и быстрее, чем в другом ответе — лепота :)
https://repl.it/repls/GrayUnwrittenTelevision

Comment: @dIm0n Хотя в итоге что-то с правильным табом уже работает не так шустро как я думал. Но всё-равно вроде шустрее.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю небольшие вычислительные оптимизации:

```
from time import time
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

I = (-1) ** .5
maxiter = 64
maxiter_255 = 255 / maxiter

def f(z, c):
    return z**2 + c

def mandelbrot(x, y, scale):
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    j_list = [I*((j / scale + y) / 125 - 2) for j in range(500)]
    for i in range(500):
        i0 = (i / scale + x) / 125 - 2
        for j in range(500):
            c = i0 + j_list[j]
            z = f(0, c)
            
            for depth in range(maxiter):
                if abs(z) > 100:
                    break
                z = f(z, c)                
            c = depth * maxiter_255
            gfxdraw.pixel(win, i, j, (c, c, c))

        pygame.display.update()
        
x, y, scale = 0, 0, 1
mandelbrot(x, y, scale)

while True:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x0, y0 = ev.pos
            
            x += (x0 - 50) / scale
            y += (y0 - 50) / scale
            scale *= 5
            
            mandelbrot(x, y, scale)
```

Comment: А вы время замеряли? У меня %timeit на этом коде замедление в 400 раз показал. Отрисовку я всю выкинул, чисто сама функция вычисления mandelbrot на первой итерации

Comment: @CrazyElf, не замерял, однако я подумал, что если отрисовка быстрее, то и решение лучше.

Comment: А, отрисовка. Да, я не смотрел на саму отрисовку, каюсь. Вот вычисление - сильно медленнее